# Error: Extra }, or forgotten \right while keeping the correct hight of brackets

Tags: errors, align, split

The following works fine,

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{split}
            \left\| \left(a - c\right) - \frac{|b|^2\cdot |d|^2}{|b \times d|^2} \left[
                                     \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{b}{|b|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{d}{|d|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{b}{b} \right.\right. + \\
            \left.\left. \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d}{|d|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{b}{|b|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{d}{d} 
            \right] \right\| = \frac{|(a - c) \cdot b \times d|}{|b \times d|}  
        \end{split}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

but if I add `&`, it throws an error

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{split}
            \left\| \left(a - c\right) - \frac{|b|^2\cdot |d|^2}{|b \times d|^2} \left[
                                     & \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{b}{|b|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{d}{|d|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{b}{b} \right.\right. + \\
            & \left.\left. \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d}{|d|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{b}{|b|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{d}{d} 
            \right] \right\| = \frac{|(a - c) \cdot b \times d|}{|b \times d|}
        \end{split}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

According to many posts, I tried several combinations of `\begin{equation*}`, `\begin{aligned}`, `\begin{split}` and `\begin{multline*}`
but without success. What do I miss?

Expected result

[image]

(Without `&` the first square bracket is also ok, but the alignment is destroyed)

**Comment, why this is not a duplicate of other questions**: To me, the crucial point of the answer is, that you need an extra `\vphantom{\frac{b}{b}}\right.\right.` and you have to add another `& \left.\left.` line.

Comment: You can't put an alignment symbol `&` between `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @campa But how can I then get the expected result?

Comment: @campa, no, see my edit. I tried and the solution there does not work. I think, there is no way around the trick suggested in the solution below.

Comment: @Christoph The phantom is also mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: OK, if you understand the problem, you know, the comment at the bottom of the page is crucial ;-) Perhaps it would be good to add that point to the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting `\right.\right.` before and `\left.\left.` seems to help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
            \left\| \left(a - c\right) - \frac{|b|^2\cdot |d|^2}{|b \times d|^2} \left[\!\!\!\!\vphantom{\frac{b}{b}}\right.\right.
                                     & \left.\left. \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{b}{|b|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{d}{|d|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{b}{b} \right.\right. + \\
            & \left.\left. \left(\left(a - c\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d}{|d|} - \frac{b \cdot d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{b}{|b|}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{d}{d} 
            \right] \right\| = \frac{|(a - c) \cdot b \times d|}{|b \times d|}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, you can even delete the ...`{split}`!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `\left..\right` at all, several instances you have do nothing, and others you can specify the sizes via `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, `\biggl`, etc., which do not suffer from problems across line breaks.

Also for a two line split like this `multline*` is easier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
  \biggl\| (a - c) - \frac{|b|^2\cdot |d|^2}{|b \times d|^2} \biggl[
  \biggl((a - c)\cdot \biggl(\frac{b}{|b|} - \frac{b \cdot
  d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{d}{|d|}\biggr)\biggr) \cdot \frac{b}{b}
  \\
  + \biggl((a - c)\cdot \biggl(\frac{d}{|d|} - \frac{b \cdot
  d}{|b|\cdot|d|} \cdot \frac{b}{|b|}\biggr)\biggr) \cdot \frac{d}{d}
  \biggr] \biggr\| = \frac{|(a - c) \cdot b \times d|}{|b \times d|}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```